# How to make a nested ordered list from array data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data like this:

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
```

I want this data converted like this:

```
<ol>
 <li>a</li>
   <ol>
    <li>b</li>
     <ol>
      <li>c</li>
       <ol>
        <li>d</li>
       </ol>
     </ol>
  </ol>
```

I will try this:

```
var makeNestedList = () => {
  $.each(array, function(i, el) {
    nested += '<ol>';
    nested += '<li>' + el + '</li>';
    makeNestedList();
    nested += '</ol>';
  });
};
```

But why is the result empty?

Comment: maybe you should return nested variable from function.

Comment: Should it not be `<ol> <li> <ol> <li></li> </ol> </li> </ol>`?

Comment: The output should be: <ol><li>A</li><li><ol><li>B</li><li><ol><li>C</li><li><ol><li>D</li></ol></li></ol></li></ol></li></ol>

Or thereabouts, as you need a list item to start a new ordered list within an existing list.

Comment: An `<ol>` should not directly contain another `<ol>`?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) and create the most nested node first and then the outer ones.

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    result = array.reduceRight(function (r, a) {
        return '<ol><li>' + a + r + '</li></ol>';
    }, '');
    
document.body.innerHTML += result;
console.log(result);
```

From the outside to inside with nodes.

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

array.reduce(function (node, item) {
    var ol = document.createElement('ol'),
        li = document.createElement('li');

    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
    ol.appendChild(li);
    node.appendChild(ol);
    return li;
}, document.body);
```

Comment: hmm, i recently understand, evidently method array.reduceRight, thanks thank you very much, and thank you about the new method,

Comment: Notice this creates invalid html. You should use something like `(r && '<li>'+r+'</li>')` instead

Comment: @Bergi, you are right, i moved the node inside of the `<li>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

You have number of problems in your code. You need to pass input array into function and return something from it. Then you don't need loop inside, since you are using recursion anyway.

Something like this I think will fix it:

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

var makeNestedList = (arr) => {
  let nested = '<ol>'
  nested += '<li>' + arr[0];
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    nested += makeNestedList(arr.slice(1));
  }
  nested += '</li></ol>';
  return nested
};

document.body.innerHTML = makeNestedList(array)
```

Comment: This is brilliant. You "loop" to your own function, from your function. I didn't know you could do that. I did add a <div id "myDiv"></div> in my HTML body part. I then 
 inserted the list in it with: document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = makeNestedList(array).

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

#### Logic

- loop over array in reverse order.
- For every item, create a ordered list.
- Append this list to next list.

```js
function createOrderedList(items) {
  var ol = document.createElement('ol');
  items.forEach(function(item){
    ol.appendChild(createListItem(item))
  })
  return ol;
}

function createListItem(item) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = item;
  return li;
}

var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

var list = array.reduceRight(function(p, c){
  var el = createOrderedList([c]);
  if(p === null) {
    p = el;
  }
  else {
    el.appendChild(p);
  }
  return el;
}, null);

document.querySelector('.content').appendChild(list);
```

```html
<div class='content'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following, your recursive is not correct.

```
var arr=[1,2,3];
var nested='';

 var nestIt=function(i){
    if(i==arr.length){
        return "";
    }
    nested += '<ol>';
    nested += '<li>' + arr[i]+ '</li>';
    nestIt(i+1)
    nested += '</ol>';

    return nested
}

nestIt(0);
nested;
```

it will display result in console.